# Mvn clean install error

Tags: java, maven

I wrote some code with Sping boot. Everything is working.
I wanted to generate fat jar file with using Maven. I entered to my project and wroted this to cmd line: "mcn clean install". This should generate this jar file, but It showed me this error:

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Tdjb.png)

My friend, on linux tried do the same and there is not erroros. Jar file was generated. So what's wrong?

Comment: It's best if you paste the text of your error message. Images aren't helpful for potential answerers.

Comment: The command to generate a fat Spring Boot jar is `mvn package` or `mvn spring-boot:repackage`. `mvn install` generates the jar _and copies it into your maven local repository_ which is probably not what you want with an executable jar (since probably no other build will be dependent on it).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you've set your `JAVA_HOME` variable to a JRE directory. Change it to a JDK so that maven can find javac and compile your code.